# add new node to an exisiting linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

when I'm trying to add a new node to my linked list the compiler stop working and fails to add the node , I can't find out the problem is it in  the logic or in the syntax

```
struct Record* CreateNode() {
    struct Record* PointerToRecord ;
    PointerToRecord = (struct Record*) malloc(sizeof(struct Record*));
    if (PointerToRecord) {
        PointerToRecord->C = FillDataOfContacts();
        PointerToRecord->Next = NULL;
        PointerToRecord->Prev = NULL;
    }
    return PointerToRecord  ;
}

struct Record* AddNode() {
    if (Head == NULL && Tile == NULL) {
        Head = Tile = CreateNode();
    } else {
        struct Record* Pointer ;
        Pointer = CreateNode();
        Tile->Next = Pointer ;
        Pointer->Prev = Tile ;
        Pointer->Next = NULL;
        Tile = Pointer ;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to show error messages, saying 'the compiler stops working' is not useful

Comment: that is what actually happened ! code blocks stop working it is accidently closed !

Comment: @AlameerAshraf Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as reading about [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], that means your complete code so we can possibly reproduce your problem on out computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `struct Record* CreateNode()` function, you have:

```
PointerToRecord = (struct Record*) malloc(sizeof(struct Record*));
```

Here you are not assigning enough memory to store a `struct record`  instead you are assigning memory to store a `struct record*`

try assigning this way:

```
PointerToRecord = (struct Record*) malloc(sizeof(struct Record));
```

Additionally, you need not cast the return value of malloc : **[Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5281962)** *(click)*

so you can allocate your pointer in the following manner

```
PointerToRecord = malloc(sizeof(struct Record));
```